# How to communicate a raise I recently received to a recruiter?

Tags: communication, salary, job-offer

Currently I am in the middle of the process of talking to a recruiter. They asked for my current salary so they can best adjust the offer they make.

I recently received an offer because the end of the year was approaching (I was not expecting it) but my manager also recently got me a sizable raise. The raise would put me more at the offer given to me by the company.

As of right now, given the raise, I'm less inclined to leave the company but I was wondering if there was a way to communicate this to the recruiter? I am not sure if its rude to ask for more. Any advice would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is never rude to negotiate, or to communicate what it will take to hire you.**

If you've received a higher salary, it's only natural to notify the recruiter, if that in fact changes what you are asking for. Don't just say you received a raise -- be clear what that means for the offer you seek.

Make sure that you are negotiating in good faith, however, and not just fishing for a better offer that you have no intention of taking.

By the way, it's never a good idea to tell employers or recruiters your current salary, no matter how hard they press. If they don't know your current salary, you are free to negotiate your true market value, independent of what you've earned in the past.